# Autofix maven checkstyle errors

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA along with google checks rules to validate code quality.
Also, I have CheckStyle IDEA plugin installed in my IDE.
This plugin identifies all the checkstyle issues.

But I'm looking for an autofix solution for these errors (at least for indentation issues and import order). Is there any plugin available for that, or can I configure Checkstyle IDEA to do the same?

Comment: I think Checkstyle-IDEA can't do this yet. However, Eclipse-CS can, so you might want to load the code base in Eclipse once, have the errors fixed, and then go back to IntelliJ. Even Eclipse-CS does not have quick fixes for everything, though, so will still have a lot of manual work left. Also consider configuring the auto-formatter according to Checkstyle. Checkstyle-IDEA can help with this a bit.

Comment: I'm not familial with CheckStyle IDEA plugin, but if it runs inspections for identifying style issues you can run them on project and then [fix them in a batch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html#fix) from Inspection results tool window.

Comment: @Andrey: I looked into that, but when I right-click on the error, I don't see any options